# How do you install an optional package when using Python Poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry, virtual-environment

Given the following `pyproject.toml` file, how do I install the optional package `ipdb`?

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "yolo"
version = "1.0.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
Django = "^4.0.4"
ipdb = {version = "^0.13.6", optional = true}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.4.1"
```

The [Poetry Documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#options-3) shows how to add an optional package to the `pyproject.toml` file, but not how to actually install it if I am given the file and have a blank environment.

Answer (score 2):

Optional dependencies must be clusters within an `extra` to be installable: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras

So, your `pyproject.toml` could look like this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "yolo"
version = "1.0.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
Django = "^4.0.4"
ipdb = {version = "^0.13.6", optional = true}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.4.1"

[tool.poetry.extras]
debug = ["ipdb"]
```

Than use `poetry install -E debug` to install this extra.

At the moment the CLI is missing an option to add an optional dependencies to an `extra` group.

Side note: `extras` are meant for additional functions of your package during runtime. If you only need `ipdb` during development, I would suggest to add it a as `dev-dependencies`.